# How to find a pattern that spans vertical lines?

Tags: python, string

```
N
|
T
```

Is there a way to find the pattern above in the input below? It's a vertical pattern that spans across several lines of text.

```
5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGCGTATTCTCAGTCAGTTGAAGTGNTACAGAA
            ::     :::       ::        : :     : ||||| :          
3'          ATTCAGCCTGCACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG
```

I tried multiple ways but I am not sure whether it is possible or not. This did not work:

```
if 'N\n|\nT' in input:
    print('found')
```

Also, what if `T` could be any of the letters `A`, `T`, `C`, or `G`?

Comment: You mean that the data, when printed looks like what you did post in the first listing?

Comment: yes, it is a value of a key inside a dict.

Comment: I don't think the pattern you think you want is what you want (there isn't any newline after the `N` and `|` characters since these are the middle of the line, but it communicates the idea. Is this text the exact string or is it a substring (possibly of a multi-line string/file)?

Comment: This is the pattern I want to search among hundreds of dictionary keys like this - ```N``` and ```|``` are consistent but the character below the ```|``` can be anything from ```ATCG```

Comment: @ggorlen this pattern is structured like this - and this is a value of a dictionary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string (DNA sequences and base-pairing pattern, I am guessing) into a list of 3 strings, and iterate along all 3 strings using the index:

```
import re

in_str = '''
5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGCGTATTCTCAGTCAGTTGAAGTGNTACAGAA
            ::     :::       ::        : :     : ||||| :          
3'          ATTCAGCCTGCACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG'''

in_str = re.sub(r'^\s*', "", in_str)
lst = re.split(r'\n', in_str)

acgt = set(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'])
for idx in range(min([len(s) for s in lst])):
    if lst[0][idx] == 'N' and lst[1][idx] == '|' and lst[2][idx] in acgt:
        print('found!')
        break
```

To find whether the pattern occurs within, say, the last 10 nucleotides of the first strand, iterate across the corresponding range:

```
len0 = len(lst[0])
offset = 10
for idx in range(len0 - offset, len0):
    if lst[0][idx] == 'N' and lst[1][idx] == '|' and lst[2][idx] in acgt:
        print('found!')
        break
```

Comment: Dear Timur - how can I expand this to check if the "|" is under the last 10 characters of the upper string? meaning to know if the last 10 characters of the upper string binds to another string - it would be great if you could give me some help - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
line = "5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGTGCGTATTCTCAGTCAGTTGAAGTGNTACAGAA\n            ::     :::       ::        : :     : ||||| :          \n3'          ATTCAGCCTGCACTCGTTACCGAGGCATGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG"

new = line.split('\n')

pos_N = new[0].find('N')

N = 'N'
l = '|'
T = 'T'

for i in range(len(new[0])):
    if (new[0][i] == N):
        if l in new[1][i]:
            if T in new[2][i]:
                print('found')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This assumes the `pos_N` will match the pipe and `T` below it, but it might not. Maybe the first `N` isn't matched with a pipe and `T` but one later in the group of lines does match, in which case this approach gives a false negative. You really need to check every `N` in the first line.

Comment: try adding reasons to the asnwer as to why you chose this and how it solves the OP problem